# How to change a light socket from being controlled by light switch to having constant power

Tags: electrical, switch

I want to remove a light and put in a ceiling fan however the switch not only controls this socket but another 2 lights in the room. Is it possible to change the one to have constant power and not be controlled by the light switch?

Comment: Possible, but will need to know how the lights and switch is wired, for the easy just change connections.  Quite possible will you need a new circuit also if it is not wired to do the easy way.  Add pictures of the wire connections at the lights and the switch.  Do this with the breaker off.  The first light in the circuit should have the important connections.

Comment: If this was installed quite some time ago, it might be a switch loop where power goes to one of the lights before heading off to the switch. In that case, it will be reasonably easy. However, we'd need to see pictures of all the wiring involved to help assess if that's the case. Do NOT disconnect anything (but do turn off the breaker) when taking the pictures, then [edit] them into your question.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?

Comment: Just to clarify: you want to swap one of three existing sockets—controlled by one switch—from a socket to a ceiling fan, while retaining the other two light sockets?  Is the ceiling fan going to be *only* a fan, or a fan/light combo?  And you want the fan to have constant power while retaining the switch for the remaining two sockets—will the fan be controlled by remote?

Comment: you could replace the lights with smart bulbs or fixtures and control them with your home automation system or a simple remote switch or an app.